# Mysql query to get all users who has bday in particular month

Tags: mysql

tbl_user

```
user_id         user_name       user_email                      user_bday
1               steve           stevemartin144@gmail.com        1970-06-16
2               mark            markm123@yahoo.com          1989-07-12
3               lee             leewilson@ymail.com             1976-05-06
4               grand           grand_elite@gmail.com           1986-07-30
5               smith           smithjordan145@gmail.com        1993-02-17
```

I want to fetch users who has birthday on month July, Result will be

```
2               mark            markm123@yahoo.com          1989-07-12
4               grand           grand_elite@gmail.com           1986-07-30
```

I have tried queries like:

get first & last date of month which we need to get result & passed to SQL query like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_bday >= '07-01' AND user_date_of_birth <= '07-31'
```

Comment: Which type is the user_bday column?

Comment: what data type is user_bday?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE month(user_bday) = 7 try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user_bday column is date datatype then try this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE month(user_bday) = 7
```

if you want particular year and month then try this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE month(user_bday) = 7 and year(user_bday) = 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your column birthday is a `date` type, then extract the month from date with the mysql function `month(date)`, see example: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php